# Custom drawing background in Canvas

Tags: wpf, mvvm, canvas, background, drawing

I want to create Program for drawing shapes.
Something like this (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1).

To do this I consider use WPF and MVVM(PRISM).

My requirement is custom background drawing.

During implementation I met with some obstacles:)

---

**View Code**

```
public class DrawingAreaCanvas : Canvas, IDrawingAreaCanvas
{
    .......
    private IDrawingAreaModelView _modelView;
    [Dependency]
    public IDrawingAreaModelView ModelView
    {
        get { return _modelView; }
        set
        {
            _modelView = value;
            DataContext = _modelView;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext dc)
    {
        base.OnRender(dc);

        _modelView.OnRender(dc); // Pass drawing to modelview
    }
}
```

Is this approach correct ?

Regards, 
Leszek

Comment: I'm sorry Lehu, but I'm having trouble understanding your structure. Is _modelView a ViewModel or a View? It appears to be a ViewModel in that you're assigning it to the Canvas DataContext, but you are then passing it a DrawingContext to do rendering.

Comment: Hello Gaz. Member _modelView is a ViewModel injected into Canvas. I am not sure that it is a proper way to custom drawing background. Finally I want to draw Canvas background "manually" in MVVM pattern.